# URL is redirecting to HTTPS?

Tags: ssl, https

I installed SSL (stupidly) to encrypt the data being sent, the only trouble was my subdomain was redirecting to my main. I changed my default virtual host back to the original settings and also ran `a2dismod ssl`. Now when ever I type in www.domain.com it redirects to https://www.domain.com and then says SSL Connection Error.

I'm hoping to either get SSL working on the main+sub or just remove completely. Has anyone got any idea why it's redirecting to Https?

My VirtualHosts file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/folder
#SSLEngine on
#SSLCertificationFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
#SSLCertificationKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sub.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/sub
#SSLEngine on
#SSLCertificationFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
#SSLCertificationKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Now if I un-comment the lines with # on and change *:80 to *:443 it redirects to the main site with SSL enabled...

Comment: Is this question appropriate for Askubuntu? I might suggest moving / reposting your question to Stackoverflow.com or Serverfault.com.

Comment: It's on a UbuntuServer so I assumed so?

Comment: @kalaracey Questions about services on Ubuntu fall [well within what's considered on-topic here](http://askubuntu.com/faq). Also, please note that even if a question is on-topic elsewhere or potentially *better* elsewhere, [that doesn't make it off-topic](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Comment: @EliahKagan Alright thanks! Then if it is not off topic, I might suggest moving it to Serverfault.com